# foreach loops with 2 mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I've contracted a simple tagging system,

My PHP page gets a string of tags,
First it 'exlpode' them and then I use a foreach loop to find the tag id in the id-tagname table,
once I found the tag id I place it in another table called articledtaged, where there two values, article id and tag id.

This is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['tag'])&&!empty($_POST['tag'])){
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];
    $tagsarr = explode(",", $tag);
    print_r ($tagsarr);
    foreach($tagsarr as $key=>$row){
    echo $row ;

    $tagidquery = "SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tagname = '$row'";
    $results = mysql_query($tagidquery);
    $tagidarr = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
    $tagid = $tagidarr['id'];
    echo $tagid;

    $taginsertquery = "INSERT INTO tagedarticle (articleid,tagid) VALUES('$yourarticleid','$tagid')";
    mysql_query($taginsertquery);
    }
```

But the second part only works once,

For example, if I have 3 tags, "cool", "wonderful", "lame", each with its own id (lets say 4-6 for this example).
The results will be

```
tagname     tagid    
cool         4
wonderful  (empty)
lame       (empty)
```

But why?!

please advice.

Comment: Is that the result in the tagedarticle table (btw tagged is with 2 g's), if yes, what is the output from those echo's ? And where does $yourarticleid come from? Side note: use mysqli with prepared statements instead of mysql functions.

Comment: This is the echoed results, the table with the article id and tag id is filled with 3 lines, one for each tag, the first line gets the proper tag id value, the two other lines are empty.    since it does echo the tagname ($row) I know it did got to the next tag, and it does try to insert that tag number into a table. but the loop just won't get the right tag id value after the first time

Comment: Are you sure table tags does indeed contain all the tags? Also, make sure you execute with all warnings enabled and see if that helps (I guess it will).

Comment: yes, I inserted these specific manually to make sure,    beside, if I change the order of the tags, (puts "lame" or "wonderful" first) it will get their tag number and insert it into the table properly.

Answer (score 1):

What if you changed the logic a little. You are exploding the tags value by a comma so why not put that right into the select query using the IN statement. Then you can loop over the returned Tag Ids and insert those into your many to many table.

```
if ( isset($_POST['tag']) && !empty($_POST['tag']) ) {
    $tag = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", $_POST['tag']) . "'";
    $tagidquery = "SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tagname IN ($tag)";
    $results = mysql_query($tagidquery);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
    {
        $tagId = $row['id'];
        $taginsertquery = "INSERT INTO tagedarticle (articleid,tagid) VALUES('$yourarticleid','$tagId')";
        mysql_query($taginsertquery);
    }
}
```

Comment: $tag needs a bit of massaging before you can pop it into SQL like that.

Comment: You don't want to throw post values straight into a query for sql injection issues and extra commas might need to be stripped so this is definitely true

Comment: No, I understand this is a prototype and we're not supposed to care about security right now -- but it won't work at all the way you wrote it; each value needs to be enclosed in some kind of quotes.

Comment: I've updated the code. It should work now. I'm so used to dealing with ints when I use the IN statement I completely forgot.

Comment: I've tried your code, and what happens is that now it only insert 1 line with the correct tag id into the table, even though there are 4 tags.

Comment: Then you're definitely misspelling some tags somewhere. Make sure to execute with all warnings enabled, as suggested before. Not this version -- this version behaves as it should; your version, which is assuming there are results to be had.

Comment: WOOO I got it, it wasn't misspelled.           it always got the first tag right.     the thing was with the 'explode' function, it included spaces. do I just added "explode(', ') <--space

Comment: That's one way of spelling it wrong... :) No, get rid of the spaces first. And I mean *ALL* spaces around commas (don't just assume you're going to find ", " and replace that.)

Answer (score 0):

Clean:

```
if (empty($_POST['tag']))
    return;

$tagsarr = explode(",", $_POST['tag']);
$tagsSQL = array();
foreach ($tagsarr as $tag)
    $tagsSQL[] = '"'.mysqli_real_escape_string($link, trim($tag)).'"';

$tagidquery = "SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tagname IN (".implode(",", $tagsSQL.")";
$results = mysql_query($tagidquery);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $tagId = $row['id'];
    $taginsertquery = "INSERT INTO tagedarticle (articleid,tagid) VALUES(".intval($yourarticleid).",".intVal($tagId).")";
    mysql_query($taginsertquery);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysqli prepared statements which work better in loops and prevent sql enjection:

```
if ( isset($_POST['tag']) && !empty($_POST['tag']) )
{
    $tag     = $_POST['tag'];
    $tagsarr = explode(",", $tag);
    $con     = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
    $select  = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tagname=? LIMIT 1");
    $insert  = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO tagedarticle (articleid,tagid) VALUES(?,?)";
    foreach($tagsarr as $key=>$row)
    {
        $select->bind_param("s", $row);
        $select->execute();
        $select->bind_result($id);
        $select->fetch();

        $insert->bind_param('ss', $yourarticleid, $id);
        $insert->execute();
    }
    $select->close();
    $insert->close();
    $con->close();
}
```